# a1.listAdd throws an error

Tags: python

```
class Adder:
    count=0

    def __init__(self):
        self.x=" "
        self.y=" "
        Adder.count+=1

    def listAdd(self):
        self.l1=[]
        self.l2=[]
        print(self.l1 + self.l2)

    def dictAdd(self):
        self.dict1={}
        self.dict2={}
        print(self.dict1 + self.dict2)

a1=Adder()
print("instance created",Adder.count)
print("enter the list1:",'\n')
a1.listAdd()
a1.dictAdd()
Adder.count-=1
del a1
print("instance deleted",Adder.count)
```

This is code that I've tried on my own, I need to add two lists and two dictionaries and print the count of instance variables whenever it is created or deleted.
When I run this program, it says "Adder object has no attribute listAdd". 
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: This doesn't seem likely. Are you sure this is really the code you're running?

Comment: No error on calling listAdd, but addition of dicts is not defined on Python 2.7

Comment: From user3424423 (still not enough rep to comment) : It works for me... Try to copy and execute the code you just posted here. Maybe there is a "tab" or "space" issue... Also, what you'll recognize when the code finally works: you can't "connectonate" dictionaries with the "+"-symbol. Just use commas instead.
;)

Answer (score 1):

The only error in the code is

```
'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'
'
```

If you try to combine two dictionaries, you have to use dictA.update(dictB) but not '+'.

Try this:

```
class Adder:
    count=0

    def __init__(self):
        self.x=" "
        self.y=" "
        Adder.count+=1

    def listAdd(self):
        self.l1=[]
        self.l2=[]
        print(self.l1 + self.l2)

    def dictAdd(self):
        self.dict1={}
        self.dict2={}
        print(self.dict1.update(self.dict2))

a1=Adder()
print("instance created",Adder.count)
print("enter the list1:",'\n')
a1.listAdd()
a1.dictAdd()
Adder.count-=1
del a1
print("instance deleted",Adder.count)
```

If this helps you, please confirm it as an answer so that someone else could find it quickly.